# How to pass/hide signed_id to Rails API controller when updating a model

Tags: ember.js, rails-api, rails-activestorage

I'm using Rails 5.2 API with Ember JS [ember-active-storage](https://github.com/algonauti/ember-active-storage) add-on and would like to know how it is possible to update a model with an existing attached image without attaching a new one? It [seems](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads) like Rails ActiveStorage needs to get the blob `signed_id` in a hidden input field to be able to process the request correctly in case of direct uploads. For example, if I try to update the model that has a photo, `photo` attribute being the photo URL, Rails will raise the error:

```
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature)
```

as there is no `siged_id` provided in the request params.

Any ideas? Or am I missing something? Thank you.